# TikZ: How to draw curved lines in simple way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby, smooth

I am a beginner in TikZ and trying to illustrate different signal outputs (base line + a single pulse, baseline + multiple pulse and baseline + sustained pulse, and so on) but have quite struggled with it.

There are other questions regarding this topic and I try different methods like `draw`, `plot smooth` and the `hobby` but the output is never like I expected it and/or really complicated to achieve.

Following some example images, I would like to replicate in TikZ. They dosn't need to be exactly like this, they are more for ilustrating porpuses.

[image: single pulse]

[image: sustained pulse]

[image]

My question to the more experienced user of TikZ, how would you approach this problem? Which methods is suited best? I often ran into the problem that `hobby` and other packages make a dip in my "baseline" before the peak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of sketch plots can be done by just `\draw` and some use of `controls`. First example code (I used a grid to position the control points):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ultra thin, gray!30](0,0) grid (5,5);
  \draw[thick](0,5) |- (5,0);
  \draw[thick,red](0,0.5) -- (1,0.5) ..controls(1.75,0.5) and (1.25,4).. (2,4) ..controls(2.75,4) and (2.25,0.5).. (3,0.5) -- (5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ultra thin, gray!30](0,0) grid (5,5);
  \draw[thick](0,5) |- (5,0);
  \draw[thick,green](0,0.5) -- (1,0.5) ..controls(2.5,0.5) and (1.5,4).. (3,4) -- (5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ultra thin, gray!30](0,0) grid (5,5);
  \draw[thick](0,5) |- (5,0);
  \draw[thick,blue](0,0.5) -- (0.5,0.5) 
  ..controls (1.5,0.5) and (1.25,4).. (1.5,4) 
  ..controls (1.75,4) and (1.75,0.5).. (2,0.5)
  ..controls (2.25,0.5) and (2.25,4).. (2.5,4)
  ..controls (2.75,4) and (2.75,0.5).. (3,0.5)
  ..controls (3.25,0.5) and (3.25,4).. (3.5,4)
  ..controls (3.75,4) and (3.5,0.5).. (4.5,0.5) -- (5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The important part here is how `controls` work. In the example below, the curved line starts at `A` in the direction towards `B`, and ends in `D` in the direction from `C`. With such components you can make the most common base functions.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ultra thin,gray!30](0,0) grid (5,5);
  \draw[very thick,blue!30] (0,1) coordinate(start) --
  (1,1) coordinate(A) --
  (2.5,1) coordinate(B) --   
  (2.5,4) coordinate(C) -- 
  (4,4) coordinate(D) -- 
  (5,4) coordinate(end);
  \foreach \Point in {start,A,B,C,D,end}{
    \fill[blue] (\Point) circle(2pt);
    \node[above] at (\Point) {\Point};
  }
  \draw[red] (start) -- (A) ..controls(B) and (C).. (D) -- (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is exactly what I looked for. I wasn't aware of this control points. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define little helpers (`pics`) for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/graph/.style={code={
 \draw[thick,pic actions] plot[variable=\x,smooth,domain=0:1] (\x,{#1});
 \draw[thick,black] (0,1) |- (1,0);
}}]
 \path[scale=4,transform shape]
  (0,3) pic[red]{graph={0.8*exp(-20*(\x-0.4)*(\x-0.4)))}}
  (0,1.5) pic[green!60!black]{graph={0.5*(1+tanh(8*(\x-0.4)))}}
  (0,0) pic[blue]{graph={0.8*exp(-100*(\x-0.2)*(\x-0.2)))+
    0.8*exp(-100*(\x-0.5)*(\x-0.5)))+0.8*exp(-100*(\x-0.8)*(\x-0.8)))}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]