# how can I write the graph in the picture in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

[image]

Using the picture, can you make the graph in latex?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about TikZ?  This is fairly straight forward in TIkZ.  Show us what you can put together and we'll be happy to help you the rest of the way.  There are numerous examples of TikZ on this site.  I would recommend clicking on the TikZ label and looking at the various answers posted there and seeing whether you transform any of those into what you want.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I second that. Especially, you should have a look to `bezier` curves.

Comment: [Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39421/22413) an example that using some basic TikZ structures and nothing too fancy to create a desired curve.

Comment: [Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530345/22413) another example using control points for a variety of other curves.

Comment: The curve part is unclear, it could be a quarter of a circle, the first part of a sinus function, a curve that starts vertically and ends horizontally at some point or even an arbitrary curve.